# Passing a link into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, link-to

In Ruby on Rails 3 How would I create a view that decides by a parameter what link in view links to?

For example to a page in my view I pass a type parameter which displays all projects in my data base and depending on the type links to either the `new` `show` or `edit` action.

I am interested in only passing on the path of the link.

I would like to write something like:
`<% link_to(enter_here_path) do %>

     <div class="blah"><%=@project%></div>

<%end%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional which returns the proper location or even creates the link, probably best wrapped in a helper method.

Something like that:

```
def your_link_method(type="delete")
    case type
        when "delete"
            link_to …
        when "foobar"
            link_to …
        else
            link_to …
        end
    end
end
```

**As a sidenote:** This kind of construct smells IMO and I'd probably rethink my design first, before I implement a solution like this. Even if you can probably find a simpler and more elegant way to write it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The snippet would live in a helper (probably application_helper.rb) file.

Comment: i don't want to pass the whole link_to command since i want to decide the actual inner text in the view, I am just interested in passing the actual link for example @project (the show of project)...

Comment: Okay. Can you give an example of the code you would like to have? In pseudo code if you want to? Or maybe what you have already? And what is it that you're going for with this by not simply using a conditional in your view? Brevity?

Comment: I don't want the condition in the code because i only want to change the link itself and not the <div> inside it

Comment: Couldn't you just have a conditional to determine the wanted path, assign it to a temporary variable and then use this variable in your link_to. This again could be wrapped into a helper which only returns a path.

Comment: look at the example i wrote in the question. only the enter_here_path should change.

Comment: how would i return a path using a helper?